# Function for checking leap years

Tags: java, datetime

As part of one of my AP Computer Science labs, I was required to write a function to determine whether a year was a leap year or not. Included as comments are a few reasons why I did things, as well as a more detailed version of the rules for leap years. Is there anything I could do better or have forgotten?

```
/** 
 * Returns if the current year is a leap year
 */
private boolean isLeapYear() 
{
    // No leap years occured before 1582 because that is when they were added to the calendar
    if(year > 1582)
    {
        // All code past here only executed when year mod 4 is true
        if(year % 4 != 0) 
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Makes sure that it does not register the beginning of centuries as leap years
        // unless they actually are.
        else if(year % 100 == 0 && year % 400 != 0) 
        {
            return false;
        }
        // Also is the same as checking for mod 4 and mod 100, since they are factors of 400
        else if(year % 400 == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else 
        {
            return true;
        }

        /*
        • A year that is not divisible by 4. - NOT LEAP YEAR

        • A year that is divisible by 4 but not divisible by 100 or 400. - LEAP YEAR

        • A year that is divisible by 4 and 100 but not 400. - NOT LEAP YEAR

        • A year that is divisible by 4 and 100 and 400. - LEAP YEAR

        • A year prior to 1582 that is a leap year. - NOT A LEAP YEAR

        • A year prior to 1582 that is not a leap year. - NOT A LEAP YEAR */
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Your posted code does not compile. Appears you are missing a `year` parameter to your method ... or you need to post the class containing this method which explains what the heck `year` is.

Comment: Ah, I apologize. The code provided was part of a larger class which had a year field that was checked for validity after being inputted in the constructor @shivsky

Comment: A possibly-irrelevant note is that you're working from a flawed spec: 1582 wasn't when leap years were added to the calendar, it's when the rules for years divisible by 100 were changed.

Comment: Obligatory discouraging link: http://tondering.dk/claus/calendar.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This question of leap years is an interesting one... and seems to be a rite-of-passage (when you do [Zeller's Congruence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeller%27s_congruence), you should get that reviewed too... ;-)

In Java, (and other languages), it is common to return-early. You can use this to your advantage to reduce code-nesting, by choosing whether to do a negative, or positive test in if conditionals. You have done this a couple of times in your code, but not always. For example, your code contains:

> ```
> // No leap years occured before 1582 because that is when they were added to the calendar
> if(year > 1582)
> {
>     // All code past here only executed when year mod 4 is true
>     if(year % 4 != 0) 
>     {
>         return false;
>     }
> ```

You have a lot of code inside that "if" condition block, but, if you reverse the logic:

```
// No leap years occured before 1582 because that is when they were added to the calendar
if(year <= 1582) {
    return false;
}

// All code past here only executed when year mod 4 is true
if(year % 4 != 0) 
{
    return false;
}
```

You have immediately 'un-nested' a large portion of your code, which makes readability better.

When you write code to match a specification, like you have here, it is valuable to include the specification you used inside your code, which, you have also done... but, do that *before* the code, not *after it*.

If you have an if-else block, and the if-side (the true side) always does a `return`, then there is no need for the `else`. This can simplify the code further....

Performing these changes, we get to:

```
private boolean isOPLeapYear() {
    /*
     • A year that is not divisible by 4. - NOT LEAP YEAR
     • A year that is divisible by 4 but not divisible by 100 or 400. - LEAP YEAR
     • A year that is divisible by 4 and 100 but not 400. - NOT LEAP YEAR
     • A year that is divisible by 4 and 100 and 400. - LEAP YEAR 
     • A year prior to 1582 that is a leap year. - NOT A LEAP YEAR 
     • A year prior to 1582 that is not a leap year. - NOT A LEAP YEAR
     */

    // No leap years occurred before 1582 because that is when they were
    // added to the calendar
    if (year <= 1582) {
        return false;
    }
    // All code past here only executed when year mod 4 is true
    if (year % 4 != 0) {
        return false;
    }

    // Makes sure that it does not register the beginning of centuries as
    // leap years
    // unless they actually are.
    if (year % 100 == 0 && year % 400 != 0) {
        return false;
    }
    // Also is the same as checking for mod 4 and mod 100, since they are
    // factors of 400
    if (year % 400 == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return true;

}
```

Once we have the code like that, it is apparent that the last `% 400` check is unnecessary, and since the comments are repetitive (the `//` comments duplicate much of what the spec and code say), they can be mostly removed, reducing the code to:

```
private boolean isOPLeapYear() {
    /*
     • A year that is not divisible by 4. - NOT LEAP YEAR
     • A year that is divisible by 4 but not divisible by 100 or 400. - LEAP YEAR
     • A year that is divisible by 4 and 100 but not 400. - NOT LEAP YEAR
     • A year that is divisible by 4 and 100 and 400. - LEAP YEAR 
     • A year prior to 1582 that is a leap year. - NOT A LEAP YEAR 
     • A year prior to 1582 that is not a leap year. - NOT A LEAP YEAR
     */

    if (year <= 1582) {
        return false;
    }

    if (year % 4 != 0) {
        return false;
    }

    if (year % 400 == 0) {
        return true;
    }

    if (year % 100 == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;

}
```

The above code is the same logic as yours, but.... more readable, that's all.

Comment: Thank you very much rolfl! I actually never considered removing the year % 400 statement, for some reason.

Comment: I might suggest swapping the `year % 4` and the `year % 100...` checks, since the latter seems more exceptional than the former. Then, we can combine the if around `year % 4` with the final return as `return year % 4 == 0;`.

Comment: Leap year calculation is a rite-of-passage? My whole programming life **IS A LIE!** (just joking)

Comment: If we are going for readability I would change `if (year % 100 == 0 && year % 400 != 0)` into two separate tests. `if (year % 400 == 0) {return true;} if (year % 100 == 0) {return false} return true;`

Comment: @Pip - FYI: [Zeller's Congruence](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/67722/zellers-congruence-revisited)

Answer (score 6):

You’re checking `year % 400` twice here, and returning `true` in both of the last two cases:

```
else if(year % 100 == 0 && year % 400 != 0) 
{
    return false;
}
// Also is the same as checking for mod 4 and mod 100, since they are factors of 400
else if(year % 400 == 0)
{
    return true;
}
else 
{
    return true;
}
```

That can be simplified to

```
else if(year % 100 == 0 && year % 400 != 0)
{
    return false;
}
else
{
    return true;
}
```

and since `return` exits from a function, you don’t need `else`s at all:

```
if (year > 1582)
{
    if (year % 4 != 0)
        return false;

    if (year % 100 == 0 && year % 400 != 0)
        return false;

    return true;
}

return false;
```

You can invert that 1582 check for consistency and less nesting:

```
if (year <= 1582)
    return false;

if (year % 4 != 0)
    return false;

if (year % 100 == 0 && year % 400 != 0)
    return false;

return true;
```

May as well invert and combine them at this point:

```
private boolean isLeapYear() 
{
    return year > 1582 && year % 4 == 0 && (year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0);
}
```

One final consideration is whether a function called `isLeapYear()` should really be a method of anything (other than a class representing nothing more than a year). Consider making it `static` and having it accept `year` as an argument.

Comment: On the topic of the static function, I considered doing so, but it was used as part of a Date class, and also was required (as this was for a class). Thanks for the review!

Comment: +1 Using boolean expressions is the best approach, and the final code is very short and sweet.  Minor nitpick: it would be a bit more readable with a few pairs of parentheses: `(year > 1582) && (year % 4 == 0) && ....`

Answer (score 5):

**Return Early**

If you return early, you can avoid nested if statements. It even fits in very well with the comment you already have:

```
// No leap years occured before 1582 because that is when they were added to the calendar
if(year <= 1582) {
    return false;
}

if(year % 4 != 0) {
[...]
```

**Further Simplify if statements**

You could also save some comments and an if-clause if you save the conditions in variables:

```
boolean isBeginningOfCentury = year % 100 == 0;
boolean isLeapYearCentury = year % 400 == 0;
```

With this, your code could look like this:

```
private boolean isLeapYear() {
    // No leap years occured before 1582 because that is when they were added to the calendar
    if(year <= 1582) {
        return false;
    }

    if (year % 4 != 0) {
        return false; // only multiple of 4 can possibly be leap-years
    }

    boolean isBeginningOfCentury = year % 100 == 0;
    boolean isLeapYearCentury = year % 400 == 0;

    if (isBeginningOfCentury && !isLeapYearCentury) {
        return false;
    }

    if (isLeapYearCentury) {
        return true;
    }

    return true;
}
```

The `isLeapYearCentury` is not needed, I just left it in for clarity.

You could also simplify it even further to:

```
private boolean isLeapYear() {
    boolean isBefore1582            = year <= 1582;
    boolean isMultipleOfFour        = year % 4 == 0;
    boolean isBeginningOfCentury    = year % 100 == 0;
    boolean isLeapYearCentury       = year % 400 == 0;

    return isMultipleOfFour && !isBefore1582 && (!isBeginningOfCentury || isLeapYearCentury);
}
```

The variables are of course not necessary, but I think the return reads a lot nicer with them.

**Misc**

- your long comment at the end should probably be moved to the top.
- the general Java style is: opening curly brackets go on the same line, `if` is followed by a whitespace, and `else` goes on the same line as the closing curly bracket (you don't have to follow conventions, but I would recommend doing so).

Answer (score 3):

A function to check if a year is a leap year or not should be a method and take the year as a parameter, for example as part of a `DateUtils` class:

```
public static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
    // ...
}
```

If you want to be *sure* it's really working, I recommend to add some unit tests, for example:

```
@Test
public void test_NotLeapYear_IfNotDivisibleBy4() {
    assertFalse(isLeapYear(2003));
}

@Test
public void test_LeapYear_IfDivisibleBy_4_Not_100_400() {
    assertTrue(isLeapYear(2004));
    assertFalse(isLeapYear(2100));
}

@Test
public void test_NotLeapYear_IfDivisibleBy_4_100_Not_400() {
    assertTrue(isLeapYear(2000));
    assertFalse(isLeapYear(2100));
    assertFalse(isLeapYear(2200));
    assertFalse(isLeapYear(2300));
    assertTrue(isLeapYear(2400));
}

@Test
public void test_LeapYear_IfDivisibleBy_4_100_400() {
    assertTrue(isLeapYear(2000));
    assertTrue(isLeapYear(2400));
    assertTrue(isLeapYear(2800));
}

@Test
public void test_NotLeapYear_Before1582_EvenIfDivisibleBy_4_100_400() {
    assertFalse(isLeapYear(1000));
    assertFalse(isLeapYear(1400));
}

@Test
public void test_NotLeapYear_Before1582() {
    assertFalse(isLeapYear(1004));
    assertFalse(isLeapYear(1404));
    assertFalse(isLeapYear(1405));
}

@Test
public void test_LeapYear_Loop() {
    for (int year = 2000; year < 3000; ++year) {
        boolean result = isLeapYear(year);
        if (year % 400 == 0) {
            assertTrue(result);
        } else if (year % 100 == 0) {
            assertFalse(result);
        } else if (year % 4 == 0) {
            assertTrue(result);
        } else {
            assertFalse(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a point in having a unit test to compare `isLeapYear` against its own logic?

Comment: I intentionally omitted the actual implementation. I don't know, and don't have to know its real own logic. `isLeapYear` could be implemented as an RPC call to a LeapYearCheckerService running on the moon. But perhaps you mean particularly about `test_LeapYear_Loop`. Yeah that's a bit excessive and paranoid, and too complex for a unit test. But paranoia in unit testing is not necessarily a terrible thing.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @Mark, you have a misconception of the [Gregorian calendar reform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar).  The problem with the previous calendar was not that there were no leap years.  Rather, there were *too many* leap years, such that the seasons were slipping against the calendar by ¾ day per century.  Pope Gregory's solution was to cancel the leap days that would otherwise have occurred in 1700, 1800, 1900, 2100, etc.

I suggest writing the code this way:

```
private boolean isLeapYear() {
    if (year % 100 == 0            // For one leap year per century,
          && year % 400 != 0       // ... except every 400 years,
          && year > 1582) {        // ... since the 1582 decree,
        return false;              // apply Gregorian correction.
    }
    return year % 4 == 0;
}
```

You could also write the whole function as one big boolean expression, but I don't think that that would enhance readability.